# There is no `std::queue::push(value_type &&)` for MSVC(C++17 enabled)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, queue, c++17

As per the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/push), there is `void push(value_type&& value );`. But when I optimized my code on `visual studio 2017` with C++17 option, I found `g_queue.push(std::move(element))` actually calls `std::queue::push(const value_type&)` other than `std::queue::push(const value_type&&)` .

For me, the `value_type`(i.e `T`) for the queue is `std::vector<char>`.

**What a surprise that there is no `std::queue::push(const value_type &&)` for MSVC**!

And as per the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/queue-class?view=msvc-160), it seems there is no `std::queue::push(value_type&&)` **indeed**.

UPDATE:

I looked the header for std::queue which is implemented by MS. There is no void push( value_type&& value ) indeed.Header path is `c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\queue` line 130!

I googled, but what a pity that I don't find any website about on-line headers for microsoft visual studio

And the `Perfomance Profiler` could not cheat me too, it really calls `std::queue::push(const value_type&)` .

A demo snippet is on the way at once.Please give me two minutes.

Here is the [demo code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed5f311ac3166325)

```
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    std::queue<std::vector<char>> queue;
    
    std::string str = "I need some help, thanks.";
    std::vector<char> vec(str.begin(), str.end());
    
   //The `Perfomance Profiler` provied by VC2017 could not cheat me too. 
   //It really calls std::queue::push(const value_type&).
    queue.push(std::move(vec)); 
}
```

Comment: MSDN is not an actual C++ manual.

Comment: `void push( value_type&& value ); (since C++11)` indeed.

Comment: What's the template parameter you used for queue<T>?

Comment: @S.M. I looked the header for `std::queue` which is implemented by MS. There is no `void push( value_type&& value )` indeed.

Comment: You're wrong, there is. The line 90.

Comment: @S.M. The debugger could not cheat me. T is `std::vector<char>`

Comment: @S.M. A demo snippet is on the way at once.Please give me two minutes.

Comment: @S.M. Sorry for the late demo code, my network is really poor. I really need some help.

Comment: Works as expected, push( value_type&&) is called. It seems to be too different from the real code.

Comment: @S.M. I looked the header for std::queue which is implemented by MS. There is no void push( value_type&& value ) indeed.Header path is c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\queue line 130! Which version of VS do you use? The `Perfomance Profiler` indicates the program calls `push(const std::vector<char> &)` indeed. I tried again just now.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/e745bad3b1d05b5b19ec652d68abb37865ffa454/stl/inc/queue#L90

Comment: @John: "*microsoft visual studio\2017*" Looks like a bug that was fixed since MSVC 2017.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Any reference?   I just updated visual studio\2017 hours ago, now the version is 15.9.36 now.But there is no push(value_type &&) indeed. I googled, but I don't find any website about on-line headers for Microsoft visual studio.

Comment: @John: The current version of VS is 16.10. So you've got some ways to go in your updating. Also, the reference is what S.M. posted.

Comment: @NicolBolas I mean is there any hint on the aforementioned link that let you draw the conclusion (i.e  looks like a bug that was fixed since MSVC 2017. ). 16.10? It should not be a valid version for vs2017(maybe 2019 I think). As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.9.36), Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.36 is release on May 11, 2021.

Comment: @John: Well, it's obviously a bug because the standard clearly says it should be there. And it's obviously fixed because the link to the current version of MSVC's C++ standard library has the function present. And on your machine, it obviously isn't there. So... what other conclusion should you draw? "*Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.36*" Maybe you could start using VS2019? They're not going to fix too many bugs in the old version, after all.